# Change .vscode folder location

Tags: visual-studio-code, sharepoint-2013

I'm programming a client side applications using SharePoint Designer 2013.

I want to change to VSCODE since it supports a lot of extensions for some Javascript library like angular, jQuery. And because of the Chrome/Node.js debugger extension.

But when I try to start any Debugger, I got the error:

```
Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder (Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, mkdir '\\servername\DavWWWRoot\sitename\Style Library\.vscode').
```

I get this error because it's impossible to create a folder in SharePoint where the name starts with dot.

So there's a possibility to change the name of this folder or the file location to any directory in my local computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to move/rename that folder. VS code is a tool that bases project management on folder content. So it is essential that the project settings reside in the folder being managed.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the "extensions" folder, but unfortunately not the argv.json (so the ".vscode" will, at least be recreated on vscode launch)

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/17691#issuecomment-559234574

I hope that'll finally change sometime .

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3884
- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/953